# Undefined reference to WinMain in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, winmain

I am trying to compile and having following problem

```
$ gcc errlib.c -o errlib.o

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.30-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.30-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39:(.text.startup+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions? These files are well tested and generated the code fine before but now i think there might be some cygwin settings or so ... m compiling on windows 8 on cygwin.

Comment: "gcc errlib.c -o errlib.o" is very confusing (it would generate an executable file with extension .o). It should  be "gcc -c errlib.c", to generate the object file errlib.o; or "gcc errlib.c -o errlib.exe", to generate the executable file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `-c` compile flag to only produce object file. Without `-c` it tries to link an executable and the linker (called automatically) fails.

Comment: but now if I
$ gcc  addtcpc.c -o addtcpc -l sockwrap errlib
gcc: error: errlib: No such file or directory
however if i list
 ls
addtcpc.c  errlib.c sockwrap.c errlib.h sockwrap.h errlib.o sockwrap.o

Comment: @user3448716 Then I don't fully understand your problem. If you just need to produce object file from source file (without linking an executable) you need to use `-c`. If you need to compile several sources and automatically link the executable after that you don't need to use `-c`. Please describe your workflow and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In fact I have one file say xyz.c but this file use some functions defined in other 2 files named abc.h abc.c and def.h and def.c. Its not working when I do
gcc xyz.c -o xyz -l abc.h def.h

Comment: Try `gcc xyz.c abc.c def.c`. Note that you need to have `main()` defined in one of these `.c` files. `-I` is used to tell compiler wich directories to scan for include files, not to supply header file names. You should `#include "abc.h"` and `#include "def.h"` in your `xyz.c` and also compile `abc.c` and `def.c`. That's what `gcc xyz.c abc.c def.c` does.

Comment: @Paul ```gcc xyz.c abc.c def.c``` produces executable name a.exe, maybe we should also use the ```-o``` flag to specify output executable name so that there is no confusion while execution.