# Undefined reference to WinMain in Cygwin when building mlt

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I tried to compile [mlt](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/releases/tag/v6.4.1) in cygwin64.

And I have linker error:
 
`` /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.7.0-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference toWinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.7.0-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x7f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain' ``

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918318/undefined-reference-to-winmain-in-cygwin) and tried compile flag `-c` but hasn't helped.

Comment: `WinMain` is for windows program. It seems mlt configure is incorrectly setting for windows program and not Unix like.

Comment: This is the configure command line:
./configure --target-os=WIN32 --prefix=../mlt

Comment: If I use --target-os=MinGW, it works, but I need the Cygwin properties...

Comment: to make a cygwin version you need to modify the configure and likely also the code. Look inside configure and you will notice that is not using automake/autoconf and it does not include cygwin as platform

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled mlt in cygwin with configure option --target-os=MinGW, but I have modified source code a little.