# Syntax error in OPEN statement with gfortran at CARRIAGECONTROL=

Tags: compilation, fortran, cygwin

I encounter some error when i try to compile a Fortran source file named 'zone_b.f' using Cygwin, to produce an executable program.

The Fortran file is download from web. The exact code can be viewed from [here](https://github.com/haddocking/HADDOCK-binding-sites-tutorial/blob/master/ana_scripts/zone_b.f).

When I try to compile using the following command it produces the following error:

```
$ gfortran zone_b.f
zone_b.f:54:72:

      call getzone(zone_start, zone_end, selection_on, line(3:76))
                                                                    1
 Error: Syntax error in SUBSTRING specification at (1)
 zone_b.f:61:28:

 &     form='FORMATTED', carriagecontrol='LIST',
                        1
 Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

I suspect it is because the Fortran file is older format, but when I try the g77 compiler downloaded from [this website](http://www.cs.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm) 
I encounter another issue:

```
C:\F\York>g77 zone_b.f  -o zone_b.exe
zone_b.f: In program `zone_b':
zone_b.f:60:
          open(5, status='OLD', file=line,
          ^

Unsupported OPEN control item at (^) -- ACTION=, ASSOCIATEVARIABLE=, 
   BLOCKSIZE=, BUFFERCOUNT=, CARRIAGECONTROL=, DEFAULTFILE=, DELIM=, DISPOSE=, 
   EXTENDSIZE=, INITIALSIZE=, KEY=, MAXREC=, NOSPANBLOCKS, ORGANIZATION=, PAD=, 
   POSITION=, READONLY=, RECORDTYPE=, SHARED=, and USEROPEN= are not supported
```

How do I solve these problems?

Comment: Current gfortran supports the legacy carriage control extension but checks validity of the settings.

Comment: There are very similar questions at StackOverflow but for different individual specifiers in the OPEN statement. We should probably somehow unify them. And also update them with the new possible support in gfortran.

Comment: Do you think we should make one canonical question about all of these options and mark other questions as duplicates?

Comment: the SUBSTRING specification error is probably the result of the line being too long. (I looked at the source, but didn't actually count columns..)

Comment: @agentp That looks like quite possible, the error message says line 54 column 72.

Answer (score 1):

The first error likely means the line is too long. Fixed form source allows only 72 character long lines. You can use more with special flags like `-ffixed-line-length-n` where `n` is a number. You can use `-ffixed-line-length-0` for unlimited length. There are many similar questions on this site.

---

The `CARRIAGECONTROL=` specifier in the `OPEN` statement is not standard.
**It may be just fine to delete it** from the open statement. I would certainly do that for my own code.

Namely lines 60-62:

```
       open(5, status='OLD', file=line,
 &     form='FORMATTED', carriagecontrol='LIST',
 &          READONLY,  err=400)
```

can be changed to just

```
       open(5, status='OLD', file=line,
 &     form='FORMATTED', err=400)
```

and the code will compile in older versions of gfortran (I tried 4.8 to 6).

You can also add `ACTION="read"` but it is not really necessary. Note that opening external files in unit 5 is not advisable, because the unit is normally pre-connected to standard input, but now it does not matter.

---

For someone else's code, as tim18 points out in his comment, current gfortran version does support these extensions. However, you must enable them with `-fdec`, they are not enabled by default.

From the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Extended-I_002fO-specifiers.html):

> GNU Fortran supports the additional legacy I/O specifiers
>   CARRIAGECONTROL, READONLY, and SHARE with the compile flag -fdec, for
>   compatibility.
>
> CARRIAGECONTROL
>
> ```
> The CARRIAGECONTROL specifier allows a user to control line termination settings between output records for an I/O unit. The
> ```
>
> specifier has no meaning for readonly files. When CARRAIGECONTROL is
>   specified upon opening a unit for formatted writing, the exact
>   CARRIAGECONTROL setting determines what characters to write between
>   output records. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> OPEN(..., CARRIAGECONTROL=cc)
>
> Where cc is a character expression that evaluates to one of the following values:
> 'LIST'    One line feed between records (default)
> 'FORTRAN' Legacy interpretation of the first character (see below)
> 'NONE'    No separator between recordsg
> ```

---

I downloaded the file. It is horrible. Don't use tabs instead of spaces in fixed form Fortran. Really don't! This file is a bad example.

But it **does** compile with the two options I already mentioned:

`gfortran-7 -fdec -ffixed-line-length-0 zone_b.f`

and the errors you reported go away.

You **need gfortran version 7**! Version 6 is not enough.

Comment: I try to include the -fdec to my command but still having the same error.

    $ gfortran zone_b.f -fdec

Comment: It is only supported in very recent versions of gfortran. You have to tell us which version do you have.

Comment: $ gfortran --version GNU Fortran
GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.4.0

Comment: where should i include -ffixed-line-length-0?

Comment: I use the command line $ gfortran -ffixed-line-length-0 zone_b.f -fdec. It leave me with the first error: Syntax error in OPEN statement.

Comment: @Shawn I missed your comment. It is perhaps better to write one longer comment. You need gfortran version 7. As I wrote i the answer, you can also just delete the non-standard part from the code. It is useless anyway.

Comment: For cygwin, i check from my setup, the latest gfortran version is just up to  6.4. I try to delete the carriagecontrol part, but it comes out with error. Would appreciate if you can specified the exact line number to delete. Thank you.

Comment: I adjusted the line according to your post. It produced an 'a.application', is it correct? Because it suppose to generate zone_b executable.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To produce a `zone_b` executable, you need to use `-o zone_b`. Please do read the manual of the compiler or some tutorial about how to use a compiler. It will pay off, believe me.

Comment: oh, thank you for the guidance. Really appreciate your help.