# Compile a C++/SDL2/OpenGL project with cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, makefile, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile on Windows a project usually running on MacOSX. I have a makefile and I would like to use it on Windows too. The thing is that I don't understand this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.11.2-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.11.2-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x7f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:70: program] Error 1
```

The compilation command was:

```
g++ -o program path/to/a/lot/of/obj/obj.o -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

There's a similar topic [Undefined reference to WinMain in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918318/undefined-reference-to-winmain-in-cygwin) but the solution didn't help me. My makefile works fine on MacOSX.

Comment: Why are you trying to build an OpenGL app via Cygwin? It won't work the way you expect it to work, since it will end up using `glX` instead of `wgl`, and will require an X server. It would be a much better idea to try to build this stuff on a native windows compiler toolchain like mingw or even Visual Studio (Community).

Comment: I'm trying with cygwin in order to use my makefile which should allows me to compile easily my project on multiple platforms because I have to. I didn't know that for OpenGL that is not possible. I'm not familiar with MinGW. What's be the easiest way to build my project from command line ? Is it possible to use a makefile ?

Comment: `mingw` provides a whole toolchain including GNU make (and a package manager, and libraries like SDL) - actually the mingw toolchain even uses cygwin, but in contrast to cygwin, the compilers and libraries actually target the native win32 APIs instead of the unix ones that cygwin does.

Comment: @kipgon judging by error message it should be `g++ -o program path/to/a/lot/of/obj/obj.o -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lcygwin -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Comment: @kipgon You probably want MSYS2 instead of Cygwin. It also provides a linux-like shell (including `make`), but uses a MinGW compiler.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Using MinGW helped me a lot and I finally manage to compile my application with `mingw32-make`. Even if I had to modify some portion of my makefile (for exemple `rm` by `del` etc.). Maybe with MSYS2 that could be easier. The thing is that, now, I can only run my app from command line, it doesn't work by double clicking on it and it doesn't ask for missing .dll.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, that's was due to a mistake. Everything is working fine. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @keltar I tried your solution but it didn't work. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @kipgon it's usually advisable not to use thanks in comments. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment